# Minor problem DebugConsole with Javascript

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, console, console.log

Here's my very simple code :

```js
let exemple = ['Michel', 'franck', 'bonsoir'];
let nombre = [8, 14, 54, 2];

console.log(exemple);
console.log(nombre);
```

So when i start debugging the console give me :

```
(3) ['Michel', 'franck', 'bonsoir']
```

But not the second `console.log`. And if i comment the first `console.log`, the console give me the second one :

```
(4) [8, 14, 54, 2]
```

[image]

Same with another exemple :
[image]

I don't have any error, and that's the only thing i'm running. Thanks to pay attention.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why, but add a setTimeout at the end of you script can solve this problem.

```
setTimeout(() => process.exit(0), 10);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Finally after comment / uncomment / comment / uncomment it finally works .. didn't understand ^^